# VueJS 3 Pushing object to array modifies previous object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to push Objects into an array in VueJS, but whenever i push a second object, it modifies the first one.

I have these datatypes

```
data() {
    return {
        elements: [],
        element: {id: '', top: '', left: ''}
    }
}
```

I have this function too

```
addElement(value) {
        console.log(value)
        axios
            .post('http://canvas-vue.local/api/elements', value)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(this.elements);
                this.elements.push(value);
                console.log(this.elements);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
            .finally(() => this.loading = false)
    }
```

The first time i call it with 'value' being

```
element: {id: 'Pc1', left: '10', top: '10'}
```

I get this output for the 3 console.logs:

```
//first log
Proxy {id: 'Pc1', left: '10', top: '10'}

//second log
//'elements' should be empty cause push is not done yet but it contains the value already
Proxy {}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(1)
0: {id: 'Pc1', left: '10', top: '10'}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]: false

//third log
Proxy {0: {…}}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(1)
0: {id: 'Pc1', left: '10', top: '10'}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

And then I call the function again with this parameter

```
element:{id: 'Pc2', left: '50', top: '50'}
```

And i get the first element of the array overridden

```
//First log
Proxy {id: 'Pc2', left: '50', top: '50'}

//Secong log 
Proxy {0: {…}}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(2)
0: {id: 'Pc2', left: '50', top: '50'}
1: {id: 'Pc2', left: '50', top: '50'}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]: false

//Third log
Proxy {0: {…}, 1: {…}}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(2)
0: {id: 'Pc2', left: '50', top: '50'}
1: {id: 'Pc2', left: '50', top: '50'}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you create a *runnable* [mcve] showcasing the behavior?

Comment: According to your log, `value` is a proxy! I think converting it into a pure object could solve the problem. `addElement(value) { value = {...value}   // the rest of your code stay untouched`

Comment: Converting it into a pure object solved it, thanks!